# Knockoutjs enable binding in namespaced view models

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm having issues getting the enable binding to work and I think the problem is due to the way I'm implementing the view models. Instead of creating view models as functions I'm name spacing them so i can dynamically build them up from interchangeable partial views.

See this fiddle for an example http://jsfiddle.net/tgriley1/4G6wj/2/

Any ideas?

Thanks, Tom

Comment: did you remove your fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/tgriley1/4G6wj/2/), I'm getting a 404 error for the web page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your binding, you shouldn't reference "vm" as part of the name.

I've updated your fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/photo_tom/4G6wj/3/

Comment: using your example has fixed it, although it wasn't the vm that was the problem, it was that i was setting the observable to null objects rather than false, which is new to me but it works. Thanks.

Comment: as with @tom, above, did you remove your fiddle, b/c I am also getting a 404 error on yours (http://jsfiddle.net/photo_tom/4G6wj/3/)?  thanks.

Comment: I havnt intentionally, but your right it doesnt seem to be available anymore, neither are my other 2. I'll have a look to see if i can get them back.. @FlakDiNenno

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess (I didn't run the code):

When you data-bind to more than just a single value (which you do by combining them using `&&`), you need to call the accessor function instead of accessing the value itself.

So basically:

`data-bind="enable: foo() && bar()"`

instead of

`data-bind="enable: foo && bar"`

Comment: You can do this, but it is unnecessary.  KO will unwrap the values automatically.

Comment: Okay, as said - didn't run it.

Comment: @photo_tom: this is not true, when using observables in expressions, you always need to call the corresponding accessors.

Comment: So which is it?  will it unwrap them or not?  would it be safer to just always call the accessor functions?